# Help with payments calculations code logic in Apex

Tags: apex

**Data Model**

I have fields on an Account. Like, `year1__c`, `year2__c`, `year3__c`, `year4__c` and `year5__c` and `year6__c`. I need to calculate the amounts and populate these fields.

**Objective**

Total amount should be equally split by the term and based on the term entered, payments need to be calculated. E.g., 3 year term would have `year1__c`, `year2__c` and `year3__c` filled in. Rest of the fields should be 0.

**Pseudo code**

I am trying to calculate payments by year based on `total`(calculated) and `term` input. So, I created an after trigger. The `total` is already present for me and the `term` is entered by user. Here's my helper method to calculate the same.

Please, suggest any tips or code blocks to do this calculation and populate the payments fields onto to account.

```
List<Decimal> payments = new List<Decimal>();
Decimal pay1, pay2, pay3, pay4, pay5;
payments.add(pay1);
payments.add(pay2);
payments.add(pay3);
payments.add(pay4);
payments.add(pay5);

Decimal Term = 5;
Decimal Total = 1000.0;

for (integer yr=1; yr==Term; yr++) {
    payments[yr] = Total/Math.ceil(Term);
    system.debug('pay year: '+payments[yr]);
}
```

Comment: It's not clear as what are you trying to achieve. Please take a look at [how to ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), and then [edit your question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/250243/edit) for anyone to provide any direction. Please note your code should reflect a specific issue and your efforts to resolve it. The more you reflect specific issue, your efforts, the more attention your question will get. In its current form, this will most likely voted to be closed.

Comment: sorry for not being clear. I made some updates to the question. Appreciate any help here.

Answer (score 2):

> **Objective** Total amount should be equally split by the term and based on the term entered, payments need to be calculated. ex, 3 year term would have Year1__c, Year2__c and Year3__c filled in. Rest of the fields should be 0.

Not going into much details and optimizations here, the below approach should get you started, you will need to take it further from here.

You can first calculate the amount to be split and then use [switch statement](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_switch.htm) here. Based on `term`, you calculate the amount to be evenly distributed between your custom fields. And then you populate the fields only based on number of terms. So your code will be something as below.

```
Decimal amt = total/term; // gives you the amount to be evenly distributed

switch on term {
    when 1 {
        acct.Year1__c = amt;
    }
    when 2 {
        acct.Year1__c = amt;
        acct.Year2__c = amt;
    }
    when 3 {
        acct.Year1__c = amt;
        acct.Year2__c = amt;
        acct.Year3__c = amt;
    }
    // just add other when blocks
}
```

Comment: thank you. This definitely is very helpful. i started off this direction. then, i noticed the term is decimal which could be 2.5 years. In that case, the above logic will not work.

Any thoughts how to handle that?

Comment: This is an approach and will work irrespective of the value. The actual logic should be use case driven. It depends if you want to round off the values or still want to go ahead with decimal. It wouldn’t be possible to solve every use case here. As mentioned, you need to  take this further depending on your use case.